# Why the TextView in XML layout is not appearing

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-linearlayout

The problem is with the `textview` which has the id `editTextLabelID` as shown below in the code.

I am trying to have a layout designed as follows: `label`:`editText`
What I have in the xml layout is, a `Relativelayout` with green background. And inside it, there is a `textview` which should be my label and next to it horizontally, there should be an `edittext`

the problem is, according to the below code, I receive the the below result shown in the image. And the `edittext`, although it precedes the `textview` in the xml layout, however it shadows it. how to place both of the `textview` and `edittext` horizontally right after each other?

***UPDATED***
XML Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
android:layout_width="fill_parent">

      <LinearLayout 
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"
          android:orientation="horizontal"
          android:background="@color/titleBackGroundColor">              
          <RelativeLayout 
              android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout00"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_gravity="top|center_horizontal">
              <TextView 
                  android:id="@+id/addLocationActivityTitleID"
                  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:gravity="center"
                  android:textSize="@dimen/titlesTextSize"
                  android:text="@string/addLocationActivityTitle"
                  android:textColor="@color/titleColor">
              </TextView>
          </RelativeLayout>
      </LinearLayout>

      <LinearLayout 
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"
          android:orientation="vertical">              
          <RelativeLayout 
              android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout01"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"     
              android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/marginTop"
              android:background="@color/bodyBackGroundColor">
              <TextView 
                  android:id="@+id/editTextLabelID"
                  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                  android:textSize="@dimen/labelsTextSizes"
                  android:textColor="@color/contentsColor">
              </TextView>
              <EditText 
                  android:id="@+id/editTextID"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/editTextLabelID"
                  android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                  android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                  android:ems="10"
                  android:inputType="text">
              </EditText>
         </RelativeLayout>
     </LinearLayout>
```

***UPDATED***
Results:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try This :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent"
      android:orientation="horizontal">              
      <RelativeLayout 
          android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout01"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"     
          android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/marginTop"
          android:background="@color/bodyBackGroundColor">
          <TextView 
              android:id="@+id/editTextLabelID"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"                  
              android:textSize="@dimen/labelsTextSizes"
              android:textColor="@color/contentsColor">
          </TextView>
          <EditText
              android:id="@+id/editTextID"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
              android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
              android:ems="10"
              android:inputType="text" >

              <requestFocus />
          </EditText>

     </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: but i want them to be aligned horizontally

Answer (score 0):

you are missing these 3 lines in your edit text

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/editTextLabelID"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
```

if you don't put it to match parent, it will be very small
the ems value is not a good use here usually

```
<LinearLayout 
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"
              android:orientation="vertical">              
              <RelativeLayout 
                  android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout01"
                  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"     
                  android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/marginTop"
                  android:background="@color/bodyBackGroundColor">
                  <TextView 
                      android:id="@+id/editTextLabelID"
                      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                      android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                      android:textSize="@dimen/labelsTextSizes"
                      android:textColor="@color/contentsColor">
                  </TextView>
                  <EditText 
                      android:id="@+id/editTextID"
                      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                      android:layout_width="match_parent"
                      android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/editTextLabelID"
                      android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                      android:inputType="text">
                  </EditText>
             </RelativeLayout>
         </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: first, can u tell me why u chnged the android:orientation to vertical? Secondly, edittext still shadows textview

Answer (score 0):

```
// try this way,hope this will help you...

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/addLocationActivityTitleID"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="@dimen/titlesTextSize"
        android:text="@string/addLocationActivityTitle"
        android:textColor="@color/titleColor"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/bodyBackGroundColor">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/editTextLabelID"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="@dimen/labelsTextSizes"
            android:textColor="@color/contentsColor"/>
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editTextID"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="text"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

in your code, you have many non-usefull layouts, simply you can do it like this :

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/addLocationActivityTitleID"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textSize="@dimen/titlesTextSize"
    android:text="@string/addLocationActivityTitle"
    android:textColor="@color/titleColor"/>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#00ff00">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/editTextLabelID"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="@dimen/labelsTextSizes"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
        android:textColor="@color/contentsColor"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextID"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/editTextLabelID"
        android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/editTextLabelID"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/editTextLabelID"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="text"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```